# Custom bottom navigation bar layout new

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create the following customized BottomNavigationBar. How can I set custom layout for the same?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEk7x.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a combination of a bottom navigation and a floating action button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabCradleMargin="20dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Add this in the Main Activity

```
bottomNavigationView.background = null
bottomNavigationView.menu.getItem(2).isEnabled = false
```

[Youtube link for fab in middle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6-_va1R788)